# get current location without using map in android

Tags: java, android

how to get the current user location without using a map in the activity? i just want to store the coordinates of the location ?
i used this code but it doesn't works !

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: `i used this code but it doesn't works !` - Please tell us what does not work.

Comment: the location always returns null !

Comment: Did you declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in your manifest?

Comment: yes, i put all the needed permissions and i implements my class to LocationListener !

Comment: What if you try `new Criteria(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE)`?

Comment: I recommend you to use [Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). [Retrieving the Current Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` won't return a location unless it already has one. If you want to use GPS location, you need to allow some time for the device to get a GPS fix and provide a listener that Android will call back when it gets a position. This can take some time. There are plenty of tutorials available about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using in my app, working fine :

```
 public class TheLocationClass implements LocationListener  {
    final long MIN_TIME_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000L;
    private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    private Location location;          //  location.getLatitude() & location.getLongitude() will give you what you need...
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public TheLocationClass()  {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public void requestForUpdates(){

        if(locationManager == null) {
            return;
        }

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,TheLocationClass.this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                Location tempLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (tempLocation != null && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,location))
                    location = tempLocation;
            }
        }
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TheLocationClass.this, null);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, TheLocationClass.this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                Location tempLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (tempLocation != null  && isBetterLocation(tempLocation,location))
                    location = tempLocation;
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates(){
        if(locationManager!=null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(TheLocationClass.this);
        }
    }

    private boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -MIN_TIME_INTERVAL;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate  && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null  && isBetterLocation(loc, location)) {
            location = loc;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Just create instance of this class and call requestForUpdates().

Variable location has newly updated accurate location of device.